# Retrieving deleted web pages

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, web

I have recently published a web service to my site through Visual Studio. I accidentally selected "Delete Existing Files" option!

How do I get back my deleted files from the server?

Comment: Check your recycle bin on the server, is there anything there?

Comment: Check your backups. If that fails, check secondary backups. If that fails, you should start making backups.

Comment: Version control, anyone?

Comment: If you don't have backups then you don't have files.

Answer (score 2):

Why, you would go to your nightly back-ups and restore the files.  You do have a backup solution in place don't you?   Because if you don't, then you're out of luck.

In theory, if you stopped the server and yanked those hard drives right now, then forensic data recovery could ***POSSIBLY*** get some of the files back.

Comment: as long as the hard drives are not in a remote data center on a shared server

Answer (score 0):

This might not be relevant, but: the one time this happened to me I was able to decompile the executable. The result wasn't perfect, but it got all the really tricky bits back.

Answer (score 0):

**IF**. You don't have backups.
**IF** you're hosting is in a remote hosting facility call them **ASAP**.
and **ASK** if they have an automated **BACKUP**. You may just be lucky.

Comment: nothin in the recylce bin.. no version control for this site.. i know i was stupid... i was developing this site jus alone.. din bother to... now payin the price.. not sure about the backup server.. have to ask my boss... dono wat s he goin to react... can u tell me how do i look for backups in my server.. i have remote login access to the server... please help me.. i am so tensed...

Comment: Look in the root of the server for a backup file?